# Displaying unicode characters in codemirror

Tags: unicode, codemirror

I have xml with lots of unicode characters.  This is coming out of a database where original ¶ is represented as &#182; (which in turn is correctly rendered as ¶ in HTML). However, CodeMirror displays as &#182;.  Is there some way of having CodeMirror render these sequences as HTML does, ie  ¶?

Comment: You have to decode entities. Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript

Comment: Figured that -- see below

Comment: And that's why you don't store text encoded to some specific output medium in a database. :)

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a solution -- basically convert the entities before submitting to codeMirror.  See [Value &# to unicode convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219599/value-to-unicode-convert)